# Spontaneity as object of investigation in the cognitive sciences

Tags: reference-request, terminology

What are known studies, experiments, thoughts and literature on spontaneity? I am looking for anything relating to questions like "What does it mean for someone to be spontaneous?" or "What factors are involved in being spontaneous?" or anything else.

EDIT: aspects of creativity, improvisation in the arts are not meant, but spontaneity in the way of life or in daily behavior. Excuse being unprecise.

I appreciate any hints.

Comment: Thank you for your question! It's currently very broad and may be difficult to answer. Is there an aspect of spontaneity that you are particularly interested in? Your follow up questions seem to focus on how spontaneity is defined (as opposed to what spontaneity predicts, how it impacts peoples' lives, etc). Can you edit your question to clarify what aspects of spontaneity you are interested in? Thanks!

Comment: Agreed. Are you talking about spontaneity in a creative sense, or in an impulse sense, or what? (Please don't say all of the above.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These should get you started, relating to spontaneous behaviour of humans in society, in contrast to [normality behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normality_%28behavior%29#Definitions):

- [Spontaneous Alternation Behavior](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nzwBBQAAQBAJ) by W.N. Dember, C.L. Richman
- [How does complex behavior spontaneously emerge in the brain?](http://phys.org/news/2013-08-complex-behavior-spontaneously-emerge-brain.html) - Lisa Zyga
- [Brain modularity controls the critical behavior of spontaneous activity](http://www.nature.com/srep/2014/140313/srep04312/full/srep04312.html) - R. Russo, H. J. Herrmann  & L. de Arcangelis
- [The Wisdom of Spontaneity (Part 1)](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/evolution-the-self/200903/the-wisdom-spontaneity-part-1) - Leon F Seltzer Ph.D
- [Identification of spontaneous and deliberate behavior](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00987461) - Vernon L. Allen, Michael L. Atkinson
- [Some factors influencing spontaneous alternation in human subjects](http://psycnet.apa.org/journals/com/35/3/237/) - Wingfield, R. C.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the start, its rather hard for me because I do not have many categories for psychological knowledge when looking for references.